# Android java, take all values from list Between position N and N

Tags: java, android, list

I have an object list which can go up to a couple hundred, or even thousand items long. This list is displayed on the screen but I only would like to display the first 50 and when going to the next page it takes the next 50 from the list.. and so on.

Is there a way to take values from list Between startpoint N and endpoint N?

Comment: why would you want that? why not to pass to the adapter the whole list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure-  either use List.sublist() to get a subset of the list and pass that to the adapter, or use a custom adapter that only returns a subset of the main list via getView, getCount, etc.  The first way is easier, but will take a bit more memory.